# Error : Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, build.gradle

I'm having a problem with Google Services plugin.

I updated google services to the latest version. I got a dependency from this site: https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.2.0.
```

This are my Gradle files:

The one in app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "********"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.2.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    compile(name: 'toolkit', ext: 'aar')

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.7.0'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.jmedeisis:draglinearlayout:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.itextpdf:itext-pdfa:5.5.10'
    compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.9'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:2.2.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.4.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:itemanimators:0.2.4@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.7.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

One in the project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Use the same version** of firebase and Google play services

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.4.2'

//Remove this dependency
//compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'

//Add this dependency if you need Google play services 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.2'
```

Comment: I did that and everything works perfectly fine! Great thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you please tell where I have to change this?

Answer (score 2):

I found this soloution

build.girdle ->

```
dependencies {
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'  //(use this latest one)
    }
```

instead of `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'`   xxx (Remove this)

Hope this will work